# Is it possible to loop over blocks in Nginx and use variables?

Tags: nginx

What I want to do is to replace the `/locale/` part of the incoming URL with an equivalent query string. I want to do this in my reverse proxy which is Nginx.

Consider this Nginx code:

```
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;
    }

    location = /fa
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/fa/(.*)$ /$1?locale=fa;
        rewrite ^/fa /?locale=fa;
    }

    location /fa/
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/fa/(.*)$ /$1?locale=fa;
        rewrite ^/fa /?locale=fa;
    }

    location = /en
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /$1?locale=en;
        rewrite ^/en /?locale=en;
    }

    location /en/
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /$1?locale=en;
        rewrite ^/en /?locale=en;
    }

    location = /ar
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/ar/(.*)$ /$1?locale=ar;
        rewrite ^/ar /?locale=ar;
    }

    location /ar/
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/ar/(.*)$ /$1?locale=ar;
        rewrite ^/ar /?locale=ar;
    }

    location = /ru
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/ru/(.*)$ /$1?locale=ru;
        rewrite ^/ru /?locale=ru;
    }

    location /ru/
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/ru/(.*)$ /$1?locale=ru;
        rewrite ^/ru /?locale=ru;
    }

    location = /tr
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/tr/(.*)$ /$1?locale=tr;
        rewrite ^/tr /?locale=tr;
    }

    location /tr/
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/tr/(.*)$ /$1?locale=tr;
        rewrite ^/tr /?locale=tr;
    }
```

As you can see, a lot of code is repetitive. This includes the location block and the regex and the `proxy_pass` directive, etc. I want to be able to DRY this part.

Basically, this part is getting repeated for each locale:

```
    location = /tr
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/tr/(.*)$ /$1?locale=tr;
        rewrite ^/tr /?locale=tr;
    }

    location /tr/
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;

        rewrite ^/tr/(.*)$ /$1?locale=tr;
        rewrite ^/tr /?locale=tr;
    }
```

Is there a way to loop over locales and not repeat this section?

Answer (score 2):

The [`rewrite` statements](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) can capture the locale in the regular expression, for example:

```
rewrite ^/(\w\w)/(.*)$ /$2?locale=$1 break;
rewrite ^/(\w\w)$ /?locale=$1 break;
```

Use a regular expression to select any URI with a locale, for example:

```
location ~ ^/(fa|en|ar|ru|tr)(/|$) { ... }
```

Or more generally (if this works for you):

```
location ~ ^/\w\w(/|$) { ... }
```

---

Example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;
}
location ~ ^/\w\w(/|$) {
    rewrite ^/(\w\w)/(.*)$ /$2?locale=$1 break;
    rewrite ^/(\w\w)$ /?locale=$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;
}
```

Comment: We had a problem that some words that started with one locale's alphabet would also be captured. For example `/transfer` would also match. That's why we have some `location` blocks with exact equal signs. Does your solution also have that problem?

Comment: No. The regular expression ends with `(/|$)` which requires the two characters to be either anchored at the end or followed by a `/` - effectively rolling both of your location rules into one.

Comment: I tested it and it worked like a charm. Such a greate answer. Thank you.